# Return an ifstream instance to use in another function

Tags: c++, ifstream

I separated the opening of the ifstream so I can loop through it without reopening it but not sure how to return it so it can be used in another function. As it is, Npc_B_File is out of scope of the second function. How do I return the ifstream?

```
void battle_start(char const* P_Name)
{
ifstream Npc_B_File(P_Name);
if(Npc_B_File.fail())
    {
    cout << "could not read file.";
    }

}

 void battle_npc(string npc)
 {

    while(btlcommand != npc)
    {
    Npc_B_File >> btlcommand;
    }
    if(btlcommand == npc_pick_dog)
    Npc_B_File >> btlcommand;

    if(btlcommand == "1" && bat_response == true)
    {
    cout << "You are in" << btlcommand;
    Npc_B_File >> btlcommand;
    bat_response = false;
    }
    if(btlcommand == "2" && bat_response == true)
    {
    cout << "You are in" << btlcommand;
    Npc_B_File >> btlcommand;
    bat_response = false;
    }
    if(btlcommand == "3" && bat_response == true)
    {
    cout << "You are in" << btlcommand;
    Npc_B_File >> btlcommand;
    bat_response = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You want `battle_npc` to call `battle_start`, is that right? And `battle_start`, should initialize the `ifstream`, and then `battle_npc` should use it, is that right?

Comment: Yes. I came across a problem where it was looping and loading the same file and wanted to just load it once. If I can separate the files then I can use the loop correctly.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

If your compiler and library support move semantics for `ifstream`, you can simply use:

```
ifstream battle_start(char const* P_Name)
{
    ifstream Npc_B_File(P_Name);
    if(Npc_B_File.fail())
    {
        cout << "could not read file.";
    }
    return Npc_B_File;
}

int main()
{
    ifstream file(battle_start("filename"));
}
```

**Option 2**

For older compilers or libraries that don't implement move semantics for `ifstream`, you can use:

```
void battle_start(char const* P_Name, /*out*/ifstream &Npc_B_File)
{
    Npc_B_File.open(P_Name);
    if(Npc_B_File.fail())
    {
        cout << "could not read file.";
    }
}

int main()
{
    ifstream file;
    battle_start("filename", file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
bool battle_start(char const* P_Name, std::ifstream &file) {
    file.open(P_Name);
    if(file.fail()) {
        cout << "could not read file.";
        return false;
     }
     return true;
}
```

As an unrelated aside, code like:

```
btlcommand == "2" && bat_response == true
```

...makes you look like a putz. Just use:

```
btlcommand == "2" && bat_response
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I am a somewhat new programmer.